# SQL Server Database Keeps Semi-Detaching Itself

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Forgive me if I am not using all the proper terms but I have databases that will detach themselves from SQL Server. In SQL Server Management Studio the plus sign will be missing next to the database, or the database will have no tables.

Now the fix for this is easy, simply detach and attach the database and we're back up and running. BUT what is the cause for this?

Comment: It happens in both 05 and 08 R2 in express, and I think standard 2008 r2 as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have "auto close" switched on probably

[Turn it off](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver16): it isn't a [good idea](https://web.archive.org/web/20160217002608/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/06/24/sql-server-best-practices-autoclose-should-be-off.aspx) And [again](https://web.archive.org/web/20130401191936/http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/practical-sql-server-45/sql-server-2008-r2/worst-practice-allowing-autoclose-sql-server-databases-140493)

```
ALTER DATABASE MyProblemDatabase SET AUTOCLOSE OFF;
```

Comment: I have not tested with it set to false, but the database does currently have True set.

Comment: In which case, this is **exactly** the cause of your problem.